# Is there a PostgreSQL equivalent to the MSSQL FILESTREAM storage?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a application to manage certain (physical) items. Now I'd like to store images and other documents alongside with the structured data.

As far as I am able to tell, the two main ways to do it in postgres is to either put in the database, either as BLOBs or byteas, or to just put them in the filesystem. Both methods have some drawbacks I'd like to avoid.

From my experience with MSSQL I know that it offers the FileStream storage method, which seems like a good compromise between the two methods above and a pretty good fit for my needs. As I would rather not use MSSQL, I'm looking for something similar for postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent.

Did you check if the [large object](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html) API offers something that can help you?

Comment: While not perfect, it certainly would work. Is there some kind of rule of thumb when the large object method is faster/better then the TOAST method with the bytea/text types?

Comment: Yes. Large Objects are better if you store really large objects and you want to handle them in chunks ("stream" them) rather than having to load the whole object into RAM whenever you want to manipulate it.

Comment: I so wish this functionality was available in Postgresql